# Delphi: Do I need to deploy BDE with DBChart?

Tags: delphi, ado

My application uses TDbChart and ADO. I was wondering, for deployment, do I need to include BDE files too?

Do you know other charting tools that can be used with ADO (freeware preferably)? I just need simple charting tool. TDbChart is a good one, but if I need to deploy BDE files too, I think it's becoming too bulky and complicated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need deploy the BDE if you are using ADO. **ADO and BDE are two different technologies to connect to an database.**

Moreover the [TDbChart](http://www.berneda.com/TeeChart6Docs/TDBChart.html) is a data-aware control, because that can be used with any [TDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSet) descendent connected to an [TDataSource](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSource).

So you can use ADO, Zeos, dbexpress or the bde components (and many more). to connect your TDbChart to the data.

Comment: Thanks! However, this got me confused:

From D7 Help file: 

"The main difference between TChart and TDBChart is that the last one NEEDS the Borland Database Engine to be correctly installed in the target machine, while TChart does not."

Does this mean that it applies only if I use BDE related features?

Comment: @AFF,i think wich exist a problem with the syntax of that help file, check this link http://www.berneda.com/TeeChart6Docs/TDBChart.html `The main difference between TChart and TDBChart is that the last one NEEDS the VCL DB.pas unit (the database core unit), while TChart component does not.`

Comment: This is great! Thanks a million, You just saved my day! :)